# 3D nrrd image visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have 3D image data in nrrd format, where the array is of shape (300, 256, 256) (meaning I have a 256x256 image and 300 slices of it, adding up to a 3d image). The array after reading from nrrd saves the opacity info for each 3D point (e.g. `imgarray[x][y][z]` would equal a number between 0-255, it's only for opacity, e.g. no rgb colors (this is on purpose)).

I'm trying to visualize this with matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3dfig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(`what do I put here?`)
```

However, matplotlib requires me to give `x`, `y` and `z` axes (plus a `cmap`), but my data is not in such format (if I do `imgarray[0]` that still contains an array of 256x256 opacity info).

I can easily view a slice of the 3D image by

```
plt.imshow(imgarray[100])
plt.show()
```

However, I'd like to view it in 3D. How can I do this?

Comment: It would be nice to upload the whole project, say to github, along with input data.

Comment: x,y,z need to be the positions of the points. `imgarray` contains the color information.  So you need to *create* three arrays with the positions, e.g. using `numpy.meshgrid`

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi yeah would be nice but the data is confidential and I don't think you'd need it as I describe the structure of it so it should be possible to solve with similarly formatted random data.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Okay, can you give me more details on how exactly? I mean, in my array I have opacity for every single point in the 3D space, so the x, y, z coordinates should contain all combinations of 300, 256 and 256 (layers, height and width of the image) and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'd say `x,y,z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(300), np.arange(256), np.arange(256))`. Or `x,y,z = np.indices((300,256,256))`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest okay, and then I'd have to flatten my `imgarray` and add that as `alpha`/`cmap`? Thing is that's a helluva lot of points and my computer's been stuck with it for the past 5 minutes lol. Is there a better way to visualize 3D images?

Comment: Mayavi might be better suited for large 3D plots.

Answer (score 1):

[Napari](https://napari.org/) can render large multi-dimensional arrays using Maximum Intensity Projection, or as isosurfaces. It comes with a GUI that makes it easy to experiment with different display settings. (At time of writing it is still in alpha stage.)

Usage example:

```
import numpy as np
import napari
from skimage import data, filters  # Just to generate some test data (3D blobs).

with napari.gui_qt():

    # Generate some test data (smooth 3D blob shapes)
    imgarray = filters.gaussian(np.squeeze(np.stack([data.binary_blobs(length=300, n_dim=3, blob_size_fraction=0.1, volume_fraction=0.05)[:, 0:256, 0:256]])).astype(float), sigma=(2.5, 2.5, 2.5))
    print(imgarray.shape)

    '''
    # If imgarray values are bytes (0..255), convert to floats for display.
    imgarray = imgarray.astype(float) / 255
    '''

    # Open viewer (Qt window) with axes = slice, row, column
    viewer = napari.Viewer(title='volume test', ndisplay=3, order=(0, 1, 2))
    viewer.add_image(data=imgarray, name='blobs', scale=[256/300, 1, 1], colormap='gray_trans', rendering='attenuated_mip', attenuation=2.0, contrast_limits=(0.25, 1))
```

[image: Screenshot of results]

Comment: Loading from NRRD was outside the scope of the question, but if anyone else was wondering how to do it: [pynrrd](https://pynrrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)